# Is it possible in the equation (c + a)(c + b) = (c + x)(c - x) to express x only using a and b?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the equation $ (c + a)(c + b) = (c + x)(c - x) $ where $a,b,c,x \in \mathbb{R}$

Is it possible to express $x$ only using $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Suppose $c=0$.  Then $ab= -x^2$, and so $x^2=-ab$

Now suppose $c=-a$.  Then $0=(-a+x)(-a-x)=a^2-x^2$, and so $x^2=a^2$

This shows that for any non-zero $a$ and $b$ where $a \not = -b$, the value of $x$ depends on the value of $c$, because for $c=0$ you'd get a different value for $x$ than for $c=-a$.

Hence, there is no way to express $x$ as a function of $a$ and $b$ alone.

Answer (score 0):

$$(c+a)(c+b)=c^2+ac+bc+ab=c^2-x^2=(c+x)(c-x)$$
This gives
$$x^2+ac+ab+bc=0$$
Now can you solve this equation to express $x$ in terms of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: The problem here is that the c is still there. I want to find x somehow only using a and b

Comment: Exactly. The closed form for the $x$ in question still contains $c$, so it is impossible to express $x$ in terms of only $a$ and $b$. To be precise, this shows that $x$ depends on $c$, so you can't express it without $c$.

Answer (score 0):

it is $$ab+ac+cb+{x}^{2}=0$$ can you solve this?

Comment: The problem here is that the c is still there. I want to find x somehow only using a and b